# Calcular a página que um ID está localizado

Tags: mysql, paginação

Supondo que eu tenha 10 registros e por página mostre 3, então o *ID 2* estará na página *1*, o *ID 7* na página *3*, e assim por diante. Na prática eu preciso acessar `www.dominio.com/lista.php?id=7` e a paginação pula para a página 3, referente à posição do *ID 7*.

É possível fazer isso em uma só query, sem precisar fazer uma consulta anterior para calcular a posição?

Comment: Não tem buraco nos seus IDs? Nem nunca terá?

Comment: @bfavaretto, O máximo que pode ocorrer é `status = false` para omitir um registro. O ID sempre vai estar lá, só não sei se a clausula `status = false` afeta o que tem em mente.

Comment: Se ele precisa ser omitido da lista quando tem tal status, interfere sim.

Comment: Terei que calcular a posição do ID antes de fazer a paginação para jogar o `limit X, Y`? Vou testar uma subquery.

Comment: Eu estava pensando em calcular antes mesmo (um módulo resolveria, considerando uma lista ordenada por ID e sem buracos). Mas sinceramente não consigo imaginar por que você quer fazer isso...

Comment: @bfavaretto, é um 'jumper' num sistema de comentário onde permita saltar para um determinado comentário sem precisar separar dos demais, e continuar a navegação. Caso contrário eu preciso separar o comentário e reformular a exibição